# Run several copies of some program from c++ program

Tags: c++, windows, createprocess

What I need to do is to **run** (for example) **6 copies** (independent processes) of **example.exe** (what is also my program) with different command line arguments from my Main program. This copies should work at the **same time**. I'm using code like this:

```
    const int NumberOfProcesses= 6;    
    STARTUPINFO si[NumberOfProcesses];
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi[NumberOfProcesses];


    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));

    for(int i=0;i<NumberOfProcesses;i++)
    {
    char fname[MAX_PATH];
    strncpy(fname,"\"",1);
    fname[1] = '\0';
    strcat(fname,"d:\\test\\example.exe");
    strcat(fname,"\"");
    int id = i;
    strcat(fname," ");
    strcat(fname,(std::to_string(id)).c_str());
    int count = (rand()%1000) + 1;
    strcat(fname," ");
    strcat(fname,(std::to_string(count)).c_str());
    int lb = 13;
    strcat(fname," ");
    strcat(fname,(std::to_string(lb)).c_str());
    int ub = 666;
    strcat(fname," ");
    strcat(fname,(std::to_string(ub)).c_str());
    printf(fname);    
    cout<<"\n";

    //Here in fname I have correct command, that runs properly
        bool t = false;
        t=CreateProcess( NULL,   // No module name (use command line)
                (LPSTR)fname,        // Command line CharToLPWSTR(fname2)
                NULL,           // Process handle not inheritable
                NULL,           // Thread handle not inheritable
                FALSE,          // Set handle inheritance to FALSE
                0,              // No creation flags
                NULL,           // Use parent's environment block
                NULL,           // Use parent's starting directory 
                &si[i],            // Pointer to STARTUPINFO structure
                &pi[i] );           // Pointer to PROCESS_INFORMATION structure
    }
```

So if NumberOfProcesses==0 it will run **"d:\test\example.exe" 1 2 3 4** from **fname**. But if NumberOfProcesses==6 (or something else) zero iteration will complete properly, but others will return false. Sometimes 4th iteration runs properly.

I think this is because when zero iteration run **"d:\test\example.exe" 1 2 3 4** the **example.exe** is busy and can not be run one more time. So I changed code to this:

```
 bool t = false;

        getchar();
        for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
        {

        t=CreateProcess( NULL,   // No module name (use command line)
                (LPSTR)fname,        // Command line CharToLPWSTR(fname2)
                NULL,           // Process handle not inheritable
                NULL,           // Thread handle not inheritable
                FALSE,          // Set handle inheritance to FALSE
                0,              // No creation flags
                NULL,           // Use parent's environment block
                NULL,           // Use parent's starting directory 
                &si[i],            // Pointer to STARTUPINFO structure
                &pi[i] );           // Pointer to PROCESS_INFORMATION structure
        if(t) break;
        }
```

So I got some delay between starting example.exe - and it **helped**. All 6 copies starts and finishes, but they don't run parallel (I have output from example.exe).
But this is not the way I want my program work.

How can I avoid this problem?
Thanks.

**UPD.**
According to Werner Henze's answer I've just add couple of lines (to **initialize STURTUPINFO**) into loop

```
const int NumberOfProcesses= 6;    
STARTUPINFO si[NumberOfProcesses];
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi[NumberOfProcesses];
for(int i=0;i<NumberOfProcesses;i++)
{
///Next two lines is important

 ZeroMemory( &si[i], sizeof(si[i]) );
   si[i].cb = sizeof(si);

/*Some actions*/

t=CreateProcess( NULL,   // No module name (use command line)
                    (LPSTR)fname,        // Command line CharToLPWSTR(fname2)
                    NULL,           // Process handle not inheritable
                    NULL,           // Thread handle not inheritable
                    FALSE,          // Set handle inheritance to FALSE
                    0,              // No creation flags
                    NULL,           // Use parent's environment block
                    NULL,           // Use parent's starting directory 
                    &si[i],            // Pointer to STARTUPINFO structure
                    &pi[i] );           // Pointer to PROCESS_INFORMATION structure
}
```

And it is work fine now.
Thanks again.

Comment: If you launch example.exe from a command line how long does it take to complete?  My suspect is that example.exe is so short that it takes less time to complete than the time needed by the OS to switch back to the original program and boot the other processes.

Comment: Yes. It's fast enough: it runs just for couple (or ten) of milliseconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the cases where CreateProcess returns FALSE you should check GetLastError(). In the code that you posted you are not initializing the si array. STARUPINFO is an input paramter to CreateProcess, so you must initialize it before passing it to CreateProcess.

I guess example.exe is running so fast that they are terminated before you come to look at them. If you printf a timing value like GetTickCount() after each CreateProcess, you will see that all CreateProcess calls occur very fast.

Comment: Wow. Thanks for so obvious and fast answer.
Really I've just add to my loop this:
`ZeroMemory( &si[i], sizeof(si[i]) );`
`si[i].cb = sizeof(si);`